# Referencing another database from T-SQL stored proc without hardcoding the database name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Sample code references table from a different database then the current on.

```
use DB1
select * from SomeTableInDB1
select * from DB2..SomeTableInDB2
```

QUESTION : Can the name of the other database ("DB2") be soft-coded somehow?

something like this ( I know this will not work but maybe it makes my question clearer)

```
use DB1
varchar @OtherDB
set @OtherDB = "DB2"
select * from SomeTableInDB1
select * from @OtherDB..SomeTableInDB2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could also use a synonym, which I find is a little cleaner than a view (the [view shouldn't have `SELECT *`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) but will also need to be maintained as the underlying table changes).

```
USE DB1;
GO
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.SomeTableInDB2 FOR DB2.dbo.SomeTableInDB2;
```

This is effectively just a redirect - indexes from the base table are still used the same way etc. So now in DB1 you can say:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeTableInDB2;
```

...without hard-coding the database.

For more information see [`CREATE SYNONYM` (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

Comment: One problem with synonyms is that it's not obvious what's happening when you read the code.  I guess you could alleviate that with a naming convention.

Comment: I like this! Thanks Aaron!

One question - can a synonym be created on a table on linked server. ie, the other DB exists on a different physical server

Comment: Yes, CREATE SYNONYM dbo.foo FOR server.db.dbo.bar;

Comment: @Andomar: I like putting the synonyms in a different schema that's only for synonyms for that database.  For instance, let's say that I have db_a that needs to have synonyms to db_b and db_c.  In db_a, I'd create schemas db_b and db_c and put synonyms for db_b in schema db_b and likewise for db_c.  Now it's clear when reading code that when you see "objects" in schema db_b that they're external references.

Comment: @Andomar it's not obvious with views either until you look at the definition of the view. Also sometimes the purpose of a synonym *is* abstraction.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Agreed, didn't notice that because we have a naming convention :)   Views have additional advantages, like limiting the columns or rows shared, allowing query hints, and rights control in the referencing database.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an interface view, so you only have to change the db name in one place:

```
create view vw_Db2If_SomeTable
as
select * from DB2.dbo.SomeTable
```

Another option is dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select * from ' + @OtherDB + '.dbo.SomeTable'
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: If I were you I'd surround the db name in the QuoteName function - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx

Comment: for the view - would performance be effected?

- would indexes on the table be used when querying the view?

Comment: The view is expanded before a query plan is made.  So indexes are used when querying through a view.